# dplyr: difference between rows

Tags: r, row, dplyr

Using this data.frame

**DATA**

```
df <- read.table(text = c("
SiteID  measured    modelled
site1   50  47
site2   28  30
site3   158 162
site4   247 243
site5   456 463
site6   573 564
site7   634 640"), ,header =T)
```

I want to create two new columns (measured_diff and modelled_diff). In these two new columns the value for site1 and site2 will be the same as the value in measured and modelled. However, for the rest of the sites the value will be similar to below

> measured_diff for site3 = measured for site3 - sum(measured for site1
>   and site2)
>
> measured_diff for site4 = measured for site4 - measured for site3
>
> measured_diff for site5 = measured for site5 - measured for site4
>
> measured_diff for site6 = measured for site6 - measured for site5
>
> measured_diff for site7 = measured for site7 - measured for site6

and the same for `modelled_diff`

**FINAL RESULT**

It should be as below

```
#  SiteID measured modelled diff_measured diff_modelled
#1  site1       50       47            50            47
#2  site2       28       30            28            30
#3  site3      158      162            80            85
#4  site4      247      243            89            81
#5  site5      456      463           209           220
#6  site6      573      564           117           101
#7  site7      634      640            61            76
```

Any suggestions how to do this in `R` using `dplyr`?

Comment: I am confused. If I follow your logic, diff_measured for site 4 seems to be 11: 247 - (50 + 28 + 158) = 11. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah, it seems like it should be `df %>% mutate_at(vars(-SiteID), funs(diff = . - lag(cumsum(.), default = 0)))`, but the numbers are off.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get a little fancy with `funs`, wherein `.` represents the vector you're operating on.

Using `mutate_at` with `vars(-SiteID)` will call whatever function you pass it on every variable except `SiteID` (thus the `-`, just like subsetting). To create the function to pass it, you *could* write your own before the pipe, but the `*_at` (and `*_if` and `*_all`) functions can take a `funs` helper function which makes it easy to create functions on the fly. If you name your function within `funs` like you would a list item (e.g. `list(a = 1)`), it will make a new version of each variable, using the name as a suffix. The function can be anything, as long as it returns a vector of the appropriate length, and can be constructed with `.`, which within `funs` represents the vector it's operating on—here the whole variable, but if grouped, the vector of the group. Thus, we can make a vector piecewise with `c`, where

- the first two terms stay the same `.[1:2]`,
- the third subtracts the sum of the first two `.[3] - sum(.[1:2])`, and
- the rest are passed to `base::diff`, which returns a vector one shorter than you pass it.

All together:

```
df %>% mutate_at(vars(-SiteID), 
                 funs(diff = c(.[1:2], .[3] - sum(.[1:2]), diff(.[-1:-2]))))
##   SiteID measured modelled measured_diff modelled_diff
## 1  site1       50       47            50            47
## 2  site2       28       30            28            30
## 3  site3      158      162            80            85
## 4  site4      247      243            89            81
## 5  site5      456      463           209           220
## 6  site6      573      564           117           101
## 7  site7      634      640            61            76
```

Comment: Perfect. Many thanks. I wish I can upvote more than one time. 
Any suggestions where can I find advanced tutorials for dplyr.

Comment: I'm still trying to understand your answer. I will appreciate if you explain it a bit if possible.

Comment: For resources, Hadley's books [_R for Data Science_](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/) and [_Advanced R_](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/) cover a lot of ground. About the answer, I'll edit with some extra detail.

Comment: Many thanks alistaire. I appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[ , paste0("diff_", names(df)[-1]) := lapply(.SD, function(x) 
       c(x[1:2], x[3]- sum(x[1:2]), na.omit(shift(x, type="lead")-
                    x)[-(1:2)]))  , .SDcols = -1]
df
#   SiteID measured modelled diff_measured diff_modelled
#1:  site1       50       47            50            47
#2:  site2       28       30            28            30
#3:  site3      158      162            80            85
#4:  site4      247      243            89            81
#5:  site5      456      463           209           220
#6:  site6      573      564           117           101
#7:  site7      634      640            61            76
```

Or with `diff`

```
setDT(df)[, aste0("diff_", names(df)[-1]) := 
  lapply(.SD, function(x) c(x[1:2], x[3]- sum(x[1:2]), tail(diff(x),-2))), .SDcols = -1]
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df[paste0("diff_", names(df)[-1])] <- lapply(df[-1], function(x) 
                    c(x[(1:2)], x[3]- sum(x[1:2]), tail(diff(x), -2)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and help